# How do I graph the p-value onto a standard normal curve?

Tags: graphics, stata

I'm trying to visually illustrate a basic two-tailed hypothesis test. I have students using ttest to find a p-value. I want to be able to plot a standard normal distribution and shade the area greater than the t-statistic. I've used the following to generate a standard normal curve:

```
#delimit ;
graph twoway (function y=normalden(x,0,1), range(-4 4) lw(medthick)),
  title("Standard Normal-Distribution (Null)")
  xtitle("Normal", size(medlarge)) ytitle("")
  xlabel(-4(1)4)
  xscale(lw(medthick)) yscale(lw(medthick))
  legend(off)
  graphregion(fcolor(white));
#delimit cr
```

which yields

[image: std. normal]

However, I want to figure out how to fill in the area of the p-value following a ttest. Ideally, I want this example to be generally applicable to any two-sided ttest. I'm trying to get something that looks like:

[image: example]

I got this from filling in the basic area on Paint but I'm trying to get something more automated and exact.

Comment: Stata technique is documented in the manual entry reachable from the help for `twoway function`.

Comment: It is, however, a statistical point that a t-statistic should be compared with a graph of the t distribution with appropriate degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nick Cox for pointing out that this exact example is in the manual entry `twoway function`.

The following gives me what I need:

```
ttest highestPrev, by(match)    // can be switched out for any ttest of interest
local positive_tstat = abs(r(t))
local negative_tstat = -1*abs(r(t))


#delimit ;
twoway
              function y=normalden(x), range(-4 `negative_tstat') color(gs12) recast(area)
          ||  function y=normalden(x), range(`positive_tstat' 4)   color(gs12) recast(area)
          ||  function y=normalden(x), range(-4 4) lstyle(foreground)
          ||,
              plotregion(style(none))
              ysca(off) xsca(noline)
              legend(off)
              xlabel(-4 "-4 sd" -3 "-3 sd" -2 "-2 sd" -1 "-1 sd" 0 "0"
                      1  "1 sd"  2  "2 sd"  3  "3 sd"  4  "4 sd"
                      , grid gmin gmax)
              xtitle(" " "Standard Normal Distribution (Null)")
;
#delimit cr
```

[image]